# Is there a way to lock PHPUnit version?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I would like to be able to run the command:

```
pear update
```

without upgrading PHPUnit, but everything else is free to get upgraded (as long as it doesn't break PHPUnit dependency requirements).

So basically, is there a way to lock a single package's version?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you have a good reason, but still: Care to elaborate why? Do you have a compatibility problem with newer versions of PHPUnit?

Comment: Yea. Zend Framework v1 is not compatible with PHPUnit greater than 3.4.  I think it get's by with 3.5, but there are a ton of depreciation messages.

Comment: Perhaps update pear, and then install the PHPUnit version you want over the upgrade?

Comment: This is the exact reason I don't depend on an intermediary layer to upgrade my vendor applications.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a simple shell script, which would do pear channel-delete for the phpunit channel, then update and then add the channel back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also maintaining a bunch of ZF1 applications and I too have to deal with PHPUnit version 3.4.15 for our tests, but we took a different approach: we uninstalled PHPUnit through pear and downloaded the source code from PHPUnit's git repo, next we build the phar package which we then symlinked in /usr/bin directory as executable.

I'm having phpunit-3.4.15 running side-by-side to PHPUnit installed by PEAR, but if you don't need a higher version you can remove the PEAR package all together.

```
$ sudo pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If you use phing as well, you need to force installation of ping in disregards of dependencies to PHPUnit.

The approach for the old PHPUnit as phar package is as follows:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ curl -o phpunit-3.4.15.tar.gz https://codeload.github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tar.gz/3.4.15
$ tar -xvzf phpunit-3.4.15.tar.gz
$ cd phpunit-3.4.15/
$ /usr/bin/php make_phar.php
$ sudo ln -s /tmp/phpunit-3.4.15/phpunit.phar /usr/bin/phpunit34
```

**PHP settings**
Since we're tricking the system a little, we need to add some things to our `php.ini` configuration.

- in php.ini: phar.readonly = Off
- in php.ini: include_path = ".:/path/to/pear:/tmp/phpunit-3.4.15"